# I had 2 RAC tickets but seat got only one

Tags: trains, tickets, seating, refunds, indian-railways

I had 2 RAC confirmed tickets, but seats were not mentioned. On the day of travel, I got a single berth for both the tickets. On the charts both names mentioned that a single seat was assigned. I paid full fare for both the tickets, but still I got a single seat. Will I get refund of my money?

Answer (score 6):

No, you'll not get a refund.

RAC tickets are often shared between passengers. You had two tickets and you got one, but often there are cases when you have one ticket and you get half. Meaning, you get to share your berth with a stranger!

Indian Railways charges you to transport you from point A to point B. For most cases, traveling is important, and even though there are thousands of wait-listed tickets that are cancelled every day, the railways lets some RAC passengers travel by sharing seats. Depending upon circumstances, it might be better than having your tickets cancelled. Imagine you booked 2 tickets, and only one of the two gets to travel while the other is cancelled.

Answer (score 3):

No, there will be no refund.

The Indian railway states RAC(reservation Against Cancellation) as:

The passengers whose names figure under R.A.C., are provided **reserved sitting accommodation** initially and are likely to get berths becoming vacant due to last minutes cancellation of reservation of passengers not turning up in time before the departure of the train.

A berth is split into 2 seats for 2 RAC ticket holders, if there’s any last minute cancellations, or if any quota allocations remain unsold, or if any confirmed ticket holders are given a free upgrade (more later), an RAC ticket holder is given the empty berth, the other RAC ticket holder can then convert the 2 seats into a berth.

RAC tickets are only issued for 2-tier air con (4 seats per carriage), 3-tier air con (6 seats per carriage), non air con First Class (4 seats per carriage), and non air con Sleeper Class (up to 12 seats per carriage).

For further details visit :

- [Details on RAC - indiamike.com](https://www.indiamike.com/india-articles/indian-railways-rac-and-indian-railways-waitlists)
- [Rules for reservation - Indian Railways](http://www.indianrail.gov.in/reservation_Rules.html)